# Building from multiple respositories in visualstudioonline

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I got a few visual studio solutions which depend on a project in another solution, lets call it the `Utils` project.

In Visual Studio the `Utils` project is added to the solutions depending on it and everything works fine.

However it means the `Utils` project must be availble for a successful build which is a problem since they are in different respositories. Locally we can handle it by just remembering to clone/pull both repositories but I can't find a way to do that in VisualStudioOnline.

I know there are ways to create a binary dependency instead of a project dependency (e.g. NuGet, add  `Utils` assembly to the repository) which I have used in other cases. This would work if we were organized and had "releases" of the `utils` project etc but unfortunatly that is not how it works in this case. 
The workflow is more like "I need that thing you already have, can you move it to the Utils project?".

I looked into git submodules and subtrees but they seem too easy to mess up.

Don't have a need to track the version of the `Utils` project in the parent project. Latest version is fine. (I will just hand pick commits from both repositories if I ever do need to compile an exact version)

What I need is something that says: **"When cloning/pulling this repository, also clone/pull that other repository"**.
Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

> I looked into git **submodules** and subtrees **but they seem too easy to mess up.** *[emphasis added]*

Why do you think they are "too easy to mess up"?

Submodule functionality is built right into Git and designed to do exactly what you are trying to do - reference another remote repo from within a subfolder of your repo, and fetch from it in a couple different ways that you can specify.

If the `utils` project is truly a folder or set of folders with a lot of items that are regularly updated, I don't see a better way to do this, that would allow you not only to get the latest version (of the collective items in `utils`), but also to track your `utils` repo and revert it or point to a particular commit/tag on it from any given repo (differently from each one) if/when needed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First, the git submodules is the good way.

Secondly, you can clone the other repository by calling git clone command through Command Line or PowerShell task. (Clone/pull other repository in Get source step is not supported)